# Parallax effect on div boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery library currently: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/, not to be confused with its more popular counterpart: https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax

I don't care if I use a jQuery plugin or not but I'm having a hard time getting a parallax effect when I scroll down with the red div on top of the white div.  **I want the same effect on those two bottom div's as I have on the white div and the picture div.**

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/rcx2zpau/1/

**For Clarification:** I don't need a jQuery plugin, I am just looking for the specified behavior.

**Update:** The only thing I see working is Scrollmagic plugin from jQuery, link here: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/, so I will try it and post results here.

```css
.one{
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.someshit{
  height:300px;
}
.someothershit{
  height:700px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax-window one" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0d/025Pikachu.png"></div>
<div class="someshit">
Heyheyheyh, some text<br>
Heyheyheyh, some text<br>
Heyheyheyh, some text<br>
Heyheyheyh, some text<br>
</div>
<div class="someothershit"  data-parallax="scroll">
HELP ME PARALLAX ONTO THE WHITE DIV PLEASE
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like that library only works for images. it changes the top position of a nested image to create that effect

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
  .parallax {
/* image can be used */
background-color: grey;

/* Set a specific height */
min-height: 500px;

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
  This is inside Parallax Div
</div>

</body>
</html>
```